# WebRequest cause WPF application slowness

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, httpwebrequest, propertychanged

I have simple wpf application which works like explorer and show files, in background tries to do webrequests, and if there is no response then application is extremely slow, Ants profiler say that PropertyChanged event is causing that slowness, but I don't understand why, requests are made in another thread with lowest priority. When there is proper response then application is very fast, same if I just don't do requests. I have tried timer to make requests but got the same problem.

```
var thread = new Thread(doRequest);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
thread.Start();
```

**Thread method**

```
void doRequest() {
    while (true) {
        lock (locker) {  
            PlayerStatus status = SendRequestGetStatus(null);                        
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

**Request method**

```
PlayerStatus SendRequestGetStatus(string param) {
    try {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url + param);
        Console.WriteLine(url + param);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var responceStr = stream.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Close();
            var xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerStatus));
            using (var sww = new StringReader(responceStr))
            using (var xrr = XmlReader.Create(sww))
            {
                var status = (PlayerStatus)xsSubmit.Deserialize(xrr);
                return status;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Why it's affecting databinding performance and is there some workaround?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Posting links to external sites is not the right way to ask a question here. Edit your question and add the relevant code parts, so that people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is the lock object `locker` used anywhere else? And where is the PropertyChanged event raised?

Comment: I have a feeling you are oversimplifying your code. Are you really not using the results of `SendRequestGetStatus` anywhere? Also, are you doing this concurrently somewhere or is `new Thread(doRequest);` only called once?